# does routers have Default Gateway?

Tags: networking, routes

Default Gateway is used when the host doesn't have any route information for a particular packet. So it will ask the default gateway.

Now for a router there will be lot of static routing information, but if the router is not able to find a routing information, it should take the route mentioned in 0.0.0.0 (which is called default route). Now is this called Default Gateway of a router?

I read few documentation, but i wasn't able to find an accurate definition for Default Gateway wrt router.

Comment: Most real routers use a [routing protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_protocol) to resolve routes; if not, you need to configure a [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) on your router...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have a default gateway (typically noted as a route to 0.0.0.0) for a router.  It's also known as the "default route".

A typical case for this is where a router has an upstream ISP that it's using for transit to "the rest of the Internet".  In this case, the route for 0.0.0.0 would be set to the IP address of the ISP side of your link to the Internet

For example, in the most basic case on a cisco router, if your side of the ISP link is `1.1.1.1` and the "far side" of the ISP link is `1.1.1.2` you'll use something like:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.1.1.2
```

...to route traffic that doesn't match any other explicit routes in the routing table, out the ISP's interface.  The active connection to your ISP installs a route in your routing table, so you know how to get to 1.1.1.2.   So if you're trying to get to an external address (say `10.20.30.40`), your router is effectively doing two lookups:  first it looks up `10.20.30.40` and sees that it should use the default route, which points to `1.1.1.2`.  It then sees the connected route for `1.1.1.0\30` in the routing table (which contains `1.1.1.2`), and then uses that to route the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The default gateway used on on most routers, for the LAN, will be the private IP of the router itself, ex:

```
IP Address 192.168.5.100 
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 
Gateway 192.168.5.100 
Local DNS 192.168.5.100
```

The default gateway assigned to the WAN port will be assigned by the ISP provider, if the public interface is connected to such. If not connected, you will probably see 0.0.0.0 assigned to the Gateway and other public ip settings.

Answer (score 0):

yes it has, go to command prompt, type `ipconfig/all` for windows and for mac https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/find-default-gateway/

you can see the default gateway. in accessing it on browser, type https:// and the ip of your router

Answer (score -2):

It's just a simple task:

1. Open your network and sharing center.
2. Click on "change adapter setting on your top right"
3. Right click on the ethernet adapter
4. Click on properties
5. Choose configuration
6. At your right in thee dialog box, there's an option "Enable". Change it to "Disable"
7. All done now ... Type 192.168.1.1 in your browser
8. Voila... It works!

Comment: Off-topic. Wrong question perhaps?